# Identity element in a finite cyclic group $G$.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, cyclic-groups

I was reading the definition of a cyclic group $G$ which states:

> A  group  $Q$ is  cyclic  if  there  is  an  element  $a \in  Q$  such that the subgroup generated by  $a$  is  the  whole  of $Q$.  If $Q$ is  a  finite  cyclic group with identity clement $e$,  the set of elements of $Q$ may be written $\{e,a,a^2,\dots ,a^{n-1}\}$, where $a^n= e$  and $n$  is  the smallest  such  positive integer.

I do not understand how $n$ can be the smallest such positive integer since $e$ is smaller than $a^{n-1}$. Maybe I misunderstood the definition. Could anyone explain?

Thanks!

Comment: $e$ is not smaller than $a^{n-1},$ because there is no order on $G,$ and neither $e$ nor $a^{n-1}$ is a positive integer. There are smallest elements on any non-empty set of positive integers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The clue is in the name: it is *cyclic*. There is no order to the elements. But if you look at all powers of $a$, you will get $a^{i+kn}=a^i$ for all $k\in\Bbb Z$, $i\in\{0,\dots,n-1\}$, meaning that the powers are in a cycle. Note that $a^0=e$ by definition, but $0$ is not positive.

Comment: so is a cyclic group something like a constant permutation of a set? and n is the smallest positive integer of one such permutation?

Comment: Yes, @SuperMaxLv4. Indeed, each $n$-cycle generates a group isomorphic to $\Bbb Z_n$.

Comment: ,makes sense thanks!

Comment: You're welcome, @SuperMaxLv4.